# How to remove /?_upage=xxx in .htaccess redirections?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am implementing a rule in an existing `.htaccess` in order to redirect a page to a new website.

```
http://my_site.com/it/partners
```

should redirect 301 to:

```
http://rvd.bbb.it
```

I have implemented:

```
Redirect 301 it/partners http://rvd.bbb.it
```

But I am redirected to:

```
http://rvd.bbb.it/?_upage=it/partners
```

and the target site does not find the corresponding page.

Why is `/?_upage=it/partners` added to the redirected URL and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is `/?_upage=it/partners` added to the redirected URL and how to get rid of it?

It is actually due to other rewrite rules you may have in your .htaccess that are executing before this redirect rule.

Use this rule **at top of your `.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?it/partners/?$ http://rvd.bbb.it/? [L,NC,R=301]

# all other rules go below this
```

Comment: I have modified my .htaccess according to your recommendations, but I still get the same issue. There is a .htaccess in the above directory, but cannot find any such rewrite rules.

Comment: Make sure this redirect rule is your very first rule and you need to completely clear browser cache.

Comment: I did that, but to no avail. I am testing your recommendation in htaccess online testers, and the rule is not matched.

Comment: Ah I am so sorry. I had a typo.. `%` instead of ending `$`. Try my updated rule now.